# Harry Potter fanfic about a ‘wild-child’ god-daughter of Voldemort seeking revenge

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a Harry Potter fanfic I read around 10 years back. It's the Marauder's Era, a new girl is transferred/brought unwilling to Hogwarts in the 5th/7th year. I don't remember her name, but she was described as rebellious, had dark hair with purple streaks... And was dubbed as a 'wild child'. Described as an extremely powerful witch, she turns out to be Voldemort's god-daughter, with an agenda of killing her father's murderer (Voldemort). The story also incorporates her friendship and eventual relationship with Sirius Black.
She's on a first name basis with Dumbledore.

Comment: *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*